# tmux up-pane/down-pane missing

Tags: key-bindings, tmux

I'd like to rebind the action of changing the active pane in tmux.  In version 1.1, I did it like this:

```
bind-key -n C-] up-pane
bind-key -n C-[ down-pane
```

I've upgraded to to version 1.3 recently, and now I get the following error message:

```
/home/myuser/.tmux.conf: 17: unknown command: up-pane                                                         
/home/myuser/.tmux.conf: 18: unknown command: down-pane
```

Have these commands been renamed in the new version?  I can't find anything which looks similar in the tmux man pages.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to superuser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
bind-key -n C-] select-pane -t :.-
bind-key -n C-[ select-pane -t :.+
```